# Reindexing elastic-search documents into another index by changing the routing key to a combination of two field values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I have an existing elastic search index with the following document structure, without a **routing_key**

```
{
   "_id",
   "feild1"
   "field2"
}
```

I need to migrate the data into a new index. The structure of the index remains the same with an added **routing_key**. The routing key needs to be updated to "field1_field2". Is there a simple Kibana script to migrate the data to the new index?

Comment: May I ask, what is the use case of having a combination of field1 & field2 as _routingId. How at search time would you provide the value of both field1&field2 to search in a particular shard. Check this doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Comment: Hey to answer your question I can derive this info as per my system design and querying needs, thanks. Was able to solve this will answer the question soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of a simple painless and the reindex API of elastic search could be used to achieve this.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "{old_index_name}",
    "size": {batch_size}
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "{new_index_name}"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "if (ctx._source.participants.length > 0) {ctx._routing=ctx._source.field1+'-'+ctx._source.field2}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make up to date query

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false // async call - you can track query progress if your index is huge - do GET _tasks/{your taskId}
{
  "source": {
    "index": *source index name*
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": *destination index name*
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
  ctx._routing = ctx._source.field1+'-'+ctx._source.field2;
  """
  }
}
```